# the existence of a function $f$,satisfying $1\le f^{(n)}(x)+f^{(n+1)}(x)+\cdots+f^{(3n)}(x) \le 3$

Tags: analysis

I have a problem and the problem is:

Determine whether or not there exists an infinitely differentiable function $f(x)$ such that for every real $x$ and for every positive integer $n$

$$1\le f^{(n)}(x)+f^{(n+1)}(x)+\cdots+f^{(3n)}(x) \le 3.$$

where $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f$.

I want some hints to solve the problem or where this problem comes from.

Thanks!

The following is the pirture my friends sends me.
[image]

I have find the problem. This problem comes from First HKUST Undergraduate Math Competition-Junior Level.

I paste the solution:

Lemma 1: If there exixts $M\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f^{n}(x)>\varepsilon$,the $f$ is unbounded above.

Proof: Let $c_n=f^{n-1}(M)$. Since $f^{(n-1)}(x)>c_{n-1}+\varepsilon x$ for all $x> M$ by the mean value theorem, $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ is unbounded above.Then  there exists $M'\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(x)>\varepsilon$ for all $x\ge M'$.Repeating this $n-1$ times more , we get $f$ is unbounded above. This proved the lemma.

Now assume the such a function $f$ exists, Consider

$A(x)=f^{(1)}(x)+f^{(2)}(x)+f^{(3)}(x)$, $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~B(x)=f^{(4)}(x)+f^{(5)}(x)+\cdots+f^{(12)}(x)$

$C(x)=f^{(13)}(x)+f^{(14)}(x)+\cdots+f^{(39)}(x)$,$D(x)=f^{(19)}(x)+f^{(20)}(x)+\cdots+f^{(57)}(x)$.

Let $E(x)=A(x)+B(x)+C(x)$.We are given $1\le A(x),B(x),C(x)\le 3$(hence $3\le E(x)\le 9$) and $D(x)\ge 1$ for all real $x$.Now

$$D(x)=A^{(18)}(x)+B^{(18)}(x)+D^{(18)}(x)=E^{(18)}(x).$$

By the lemma, $E$ is unbounded above,a contradiction to $E(x) \le 9$ for all real $x$.

The link is https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/ug/competition/award.php where you can  find the solutions to other problems.

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: @Ethan Bolker This is a problem my friend sends me and he doesn't know where the problem comes from. I paste the picture my friend sends me.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker  It is said it comes from First HKUST Undergraduate Math Competition-Junior Level-April 27,2013.  I have find the solution.